# Use of WebServiceHost2Factory

Tags: wcf, rest, c#-4.0

What is the use of "WebServiceHost2Factory".
I am creating Rest Wcf service.
I am using VS2010 so do I need to install WCF Rest Starter Kit??
When I added  WebServiceHost2Factory to my service markup  I am  getting an error saying 
"The CLR Type 'Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost2Factory' could not be loaded during service compilation".
What am I missing here.
here is my markUp for Service.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WCFRESTService1.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" Factory = "Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost2Factory"  %>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use WebServiceHost2Factory and WebProtocolException for Error Handling

A large part of building an API is ensuring there is adequate error handling in place to help the user implement your API. Up until the release of WebServiceHost2Factory, returning the appropriate HTTP response code and message was a chore. Luckily for us we can achieve this feat quickly and easily by utilising the WebServiceHost2Factory and WebProtocoException classes.

The above text is from the following [link](http://benjii.me/2010/03/5-lifesaving-tips-for-creating-a-wcf-restful-api-in-net-4/)

The below help to troubleshoot your problem can be found from the following [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2005/12/15/504420.aspx).

Parser Error: Service Type Could Not Be Loaded During Compilation

You may get the following error message when you navigate a WCF service (.svc file) from a browser:

The CLR Type 'XXXX' could not be loaded during service compilation. Verify that this type is either defined in a source file located in the application's \App_Code directory, contained in a compiled assembly located in the application's \bin directory, or present in an assembly installed in the Global Assembly Cache. Note that the type name is case-sensitive and that the directories such as \App_Code and \bin must be located in the application's root directory and cannot be nested in subdirectories.

The error message is pretty explainable by itself. However, I still want to point out different situations when this can happen. Here is the format of the Service Directive of a .svc file:

```
<%@Service language=c# Class="<Managed Type>" [Other attributes] %>
```

Here are possible reasons why this can happen:

- The specified string for the “Class” attribute does not represent an existing CLR type. Sometimes, this may be due to a typo. This string is case-sensitive. Also if you copy this from MS-Word, the quotes may be some special Unicode characters instead of the real ASCII quotes.
- If you have the assembly (containing the service type) in the \bin directory, it is possible that you did not create a virtual directory so that its root directory contains \bin as its immediate sub-directory.
- If you have your type in a code file under \App_Code, it may be due to the same reason as above.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your suggestion.I will check those links.